# how to get both month name and year from field and by w

Tags: sql

I have to fetch both month name and year from field in my table but writing below query I am getting an error. Kindly do the needful to rectify my error.
Thanks in advance.

Query:

```
select SUM(p.Actual_Amount) as buying,
    SUM(p.TotalPackageCost) as selling,
    (SUM(p.TotalPackageCost) - SUM(p.Actual_Amount)) as profit,
    COUNT(e.Enquiry_Id) as Sales,
    DATENAME(MM,e.Arrives_On) as Month,
    (DATENAME(MONTH,e.Arrives_On) +'-'+ DATENAME(YYYY,e.Arrives_On)) as Date  
from Pricing p 
    inner join Enquiry e on e.Enquiry_Id = p.Enquiry_Id where  e.Agent_Name ='Ish Travels' and  e.status = 'Confirmed By Company' 
group by DATENAME(MM,e.Arrives_On)
order by Month desc
```

But I am getting the error:

> Column 'Enquiry.Arrives_On' is invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

Please help me to resolve the error.

Comment: You're grouping on the name of the month. You can't get the year for the group like this. You need to rethink what you want here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your group by clause is not complete. Every expression in your projection which is not contained in an aggregate function has to be used in group by. I'm pretty sure this is working:

```
select
    SUM(p.Actual_Amount) as buying,
    SUM(p.TotalPackageCost) as selling,
    (SUM(p.TotalPackageCost) - SUM(p.Actual_Amount)) as profit,
    COUNT(e.Enquiry_Id) as Sales,
    DATENAME(MM,e.Arrives_On) as Month,
    (DATENAME(MONTH,e.Arrives_On) +'-'+ DATENAME(YYYY,e.Arrives_On)) as Date  

from
    Pricing p inner join Enquiry e on e.Enquiry_Id = p.Enquiry_Id

where
    e.Agent_Name ='Ish Travels'
and
    e.status = 'Confirmed By Company'

group by
    DATENAME(MM,e.Arrives_On),
    (DATENAME(MONTH,e.Arrives_On) +'-'+ DATENAME(YYYY,e.Arrives_On))

order by
    5 desc
```

Comment: thx 4 help its working bt i am getting result as Sep 2013 Oct 2013 April 2013 bt april should come first